# extjs JsonP proxy can't load large amounts of data

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, sencha-touch-2, jsonp

I have a store with JsonP proxy, the store is loading just fine when I'm loading about 2500 records, but when it exceeds that, it is giving me this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Ext.data.JsonP.callback1 is not a function
```

The error is in the output PHP file, below is my store code:

```
Ext.define('DVD.store.DVDOnline', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    requires: [
        'DVD.model.DVD'
    ],
    config: {
        model: 'DVD.model.DVD',
        storeId: 'DVDOnlineStore',
        autoLoad: false,
        proxy: {
            type: 'jsonp',
            url: 'http://' + ((localStorage.getItem('serverIP') == null) ? "127.0.0.1" : localStorage.getItem('serverIP')) + '/mobile_apps/stores/DVD/test.php',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'responseData.feed.entries'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Please note that the store is NOT rendering on any list, I'm just loading without rending it so I rule out browser buffer overflow as a cause of this, the error is thrown when I call load() on the above store.

The JsonP file is about 400 kb in size, and it has 3000 records, each record has 3 columns.

I first thought maybe it is a character, so I replaced all my data with "test test", it did not work!

So is there a limit to how big a file can be? Or how many records a store can have?

I'm hoping someone will take the time to look into this and provide me with an answer, I have been searching for this for a while to no avail.

Thanks

Comment: Did you look at the response? Is it wellformed JavaScript or there an error on the server side?

Comment: The response file is not supposed to be fired on its own, when you do run the response on its own it surely will give the above error "Not a function", but it is supposed to be fired from within the application! the code works 100% when I'm limited the output data to 2000 records, it only gives an error when the data is above 2500 or so. The output is `Ext.data.JsonP.callbackX(json_output.....)` The json output inside is 100% valid json, I've checked more than once

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem I suggest you to use the [buffer](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/extjs-build/examples/grid/infinite-scroll-grid-tuner.html) functionality of the store. This could avoid your store size problem.